# How can I pass arguments with UIActionSheet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an Action Sheet popping up and I want to pass a certain argument to a button processing method.

#### For example:

I have a table and I want to pass to a button processing method row number that was selected in a table.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to set this in your delegate ahead of time. You can then use this value when your delegate receives the button press notification.

Answer (score 3):

If it is an integer argument, put it as the `tag` property of the action sheet. Otherwise, you can subclass the action sheet and put variables there, or use associative references.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to pass an integer, use UIActionSheet.tag.
if you want to pass a NSString, use UIActionSheet.accessibilityValue.

these are simple and easy. no need to create an instance variable.